# Limits of Charter City authority in California

Tags: united-states, local-government, california

Can charter cities in California legalize the use of recreational drugs? Can they control the structure of their police departments? I know they can have novel forms of government, and that they are granted greater authority over 'municipal affairs', but I dont know what municipal affairs are exactly, in California.

Comment: You *can* do anything. Whether you have the political clout to make it stick despite the theoretical opposition by the *federales* is a different story.

Comment: I'm asking because I have heard of cities in other States doing this, and getting away with it. Medical marijuana is already legal in California, and Californian charter cities don't have to follow all the state laws. 

Actually, Now that I have read the state law on medical marijuana use, I think a charter city could effectively remove any limits on the use of marijuana.

Answer (score 1):

*Limits of Charter City authority in California*

According to an Institute for Local Government article, [Local Agency Powers and Limitations](https://www.ca-ilg.org/sites/main/files/file-attachments/local_agency_powers_and_limitations_3.pdf):

> Under California’s Constitution, certain kinds of cities have an additional measure of protection from state preemption. Charter cities have an extra measure of authority over municipal affairs. If a matter is a "municipal affair" (and not a “matter of statewide concern”), a charter city has power to act, even to the extent that the city’s action may be at odds with a state law. The chief restriction on local action under these circumstances is whether the action would be inconsistent with the city’s charter or the state and federal constitutions.
>
> In a charter city, the residents adopt a charter. This charter functions as a local constitution that provides for the organization and structure of the city. It also can create limits on city powers and functions. Some charters have a great deal of detail; others are quite brief. Either way, when  residents have determined that their city should be a charter city, their city then has the option deviating from state law with respect to municipal affairs.
>
> Courts, rather than the Legislature, are the ultimate deciders of whether a subject is a municipal affair or a matter of statewide concern.
> This determination is made on a case-by-case basis, which means that it frequently takes litigation to determine the scope of charter cities’ exercise of authority.

---

*Q: Can charter cities in California legalize the use of recreational drugs?*

Unlikely. The legality of the use of recreational drugs appears to be a “matter of statewide concern” thus not a "municipal affair".

> As of November 2016, voters of California passed Prop 64, which decriminalized the recreational use of marijuana. That means that weed and all of its derivatives are legal to buy, possess and consume in the Golden State. [[California Drug Laws](https://lajolla.com/article/california-drug-laws/)]

For other drugs, it would be a matter for the court to decide.

*Q: Can they control the structure of their police departments?*

Likely. The *structure* of their police department appears to be a matter of "municipal affair" not a “matter of statewide concern”. However, the *structure* of a police department may be challenged if such a *structure* is in some way discriminatory.